# Australia visitor visa: are the additional attachments after payment necessary?

Tags: visas, australia

I am applying for an Australia visitor visa (subclass 600). There is a list of documents to attach to the application before submitting and paying, and then the ability to attach more documents after paying.

Before paying, the list is:

- Financial Capacity - Personal, Evidence of
- National Identity Document (other than Passport)
- Invitation, Evidence of
- Planned tourism activities, Evidence of
- Travel Document
- Travel history, Evidence of

My assumption was that this is sufficient for an application. However, I am surprised to see the absence of e.g. a photograph that other countries with similar visa requirements insist on (although a few of the identification documents have my photo on them).

After paying, there is an option to attach additional evidence, where a choice can be made from hundreds of documents, most of them irrelevant to me, e.g. Australian passport (I'm not Australian), UNHCR document, death certificate etc... I see that there is a space here to attach a photo, but is this necessary?

Should I scan every single item on this list looking for something that might possibly apply to me?

Comment: Are you dead?  If not, you can probably skip providing your death certificate.

Answer (score 1):

If the additional documents do not contribute to your application and its review, then it's not advisable to provide them. While you would want to provide as much information as possible, better to follow the checklist guidance, rather than adding extraneous papers.

The [Visitor visa (subclass 600) Tourist Stream: document checklist](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/600-/Visitor-visa-(subclass-600)-Tourist-Stream-document-checklist) clarifies how and what to do. And note that it says that, if you are outside Australia, your nearest [immigration office outside Australia](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/about/contact/offices-locations) is in the best position to tell what documents to provide.​

As for the photograph, the directions are clear:

> [**Do I need to provide my photograph and fingerprints if I lodge my visa application online?**](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/lega/lega/form/immi-faqs/i-want-to-lodge-my-visa-application-electronically-do-i-still-have-to-get-my-photograph-and-fingerprints-taken)
>
> If applying in Australia: you do not have to provide your photograph and fingerprints unless we ask you to.
>
> If applying from outside Australia: it will depend on:
>
> - whether the country you are in is one of the [countries included in the biometrics programme](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa/biom/biometrics-countries).
> - the type of visa you apply for and whether it is on the list of included visa subclasses.
>
> We will contact you in writing if you need to provide your photograph and fingerprints. If your online lodgement is unsuccessful, you will need to go to an Australian Visa Application Centre to lodge your visa application. We will take your photograph and scan your fingerprints there.​​​